# Emacs “Ctrl+.” and “Ctrl+,” don't work in terminal

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, emacs

I use **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>** and **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>** in Emacs.  These work well on X displays, but not in a terminal window.

Other combinations, such as **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>** and **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>** both work for me.

Why do some combinations work only in a graphical Emacs, and not on a terminal?

Comment: The same happens here. Emacs 24.3 on Linux openSuse 42.2, here. Interesting, I rarely use emacs on a terminal so I never noticed it, good catch

Comment: See the answers to this question: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/1020/11